# BIRT - How to List the Contents of Page Variable

Tags: birt

I have a report with page variable implemented to display current/total page numbers for each customer. I have another requirement - Display a list of customer names and the respective page numbers contained in the report on the last page of the report(such as Company A - 3 pages, Company B - 4 pages). 
It has to be proper looking with border lines.
I was able to implement the page variable by simply borrowing the code I've found on the Internet, but have no idea how to display the contents(customer names and page numbers) as a list at the end of the report.
Would someone help me to accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with BIRT.

In similar cases, and only for the special case of PDF output, we are using a post-processing approach, but it requires Java programming:

First, we let BIRT generate Table-of-Content entries ("outline" in PDF speech) for the companies.

The second-step is post-processing: we read the PDF using iText and examine the TOC. That way we get the information about which company starts at which page number. Together with the total page number it is easy to compute how many pages each company takes.

Then iText can generate and add a visible TOC (as you described) to the PDF.